# Modulo Power function in J

Tags: modulo, j, exponentiation

If I want to compute a^b mod c then there is an efficient way of doing this, without computing a^b in full.

However, when programming, if I write `f g x` then g(x) is computed regardless of `f`.

J provides for composing f and g in special cases, and the modulo power function is one of them. For instance, the following runs extremely quickly.

```
1000&| @ (2&^) 10000000x
```

This is because the 'atop' conjunction `@` tells the language to compose the functions if possible. If I remove it, it goes unbearably slowly.

If however I want to work with x^x , then `^~` no longer works and I get limit errors for large values. Binding those large values however does work.

So

```
999&| @ (100333454&^) 100333454x
```

executes nice and fast but

```
999&| @ ^~ 100333454x
```

gives me a limit error - the RHS is too big.

Am I right in thinking that in this case, J is not using an efficient power-modulo algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [special code page](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/special.htm):

```
m&|@^       dyad    avoids exponentiation for integer arguments
m&|@(n&^)   monad   avoids exponentiation for integer arguments
```

The case for `^~` is not supported by special code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Pascal-J/BN-openssl-bindings-for-J

includes bindings for openssl (distributed with J on windows, and pre-installed on all other compatible systems)'s BN library including modexp.  The x ^ x case will be especially efficient due to fewer parameters converted from J to "C" (BN)